# Explicit Inverse Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've been thinking about this question for quite a while now, but can't seem to figure it out. We hav got a multivalued function with two parameters which is given by,
$$
f_{\alpha,\gamma}: 
\begin{pmatrix} t \\ v \\ \end{pmatrix} \mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix} t+v \\ \alpha v - \gamma \cos(t+v) \end{pmatrix}.
$$
With $\gamma >0$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$.
For this function I need to find an *explicit* inverse. My first try was to calculate the Jacobi-Determinant and got,

$$
Df(t,v) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
\gamma \sin(t+v) & \alpha + \gamma \sin (t+v)\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So $\det Df(t,v) = \alpha$ and because $\alpha \in (0,1)$ the function is most likely invertible. The question they now ask is: Show that $f$ is invertible by giving the explicit funtion $f^{-1}$. But I really don't really know what to do next.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You have $x = t+v$ and $y = \alpha v - \gamma \cos (t+v)$. Can you write $t$ and $v$ as functions of $x,y$?

Comment: in the first case it's easy, in the second case I can't, that is the problem.

Comment: What are the first and second cases here? And what have you got?

Comment: When I try to work out $v$ as a function of $y$, I can't get rid of the $v$ after the $\alpha$. So I get:
$v = \arccos(\frac{y-\alpha v}{\gamma})-t$. But the $v$ is still after the $\alpha$.

Comment: You took the wrong route (nothing to worry about, happens all the time). What is $y + \gamma \cos x$?

Comment: I don't really know any trig-identity which looks like that. Or am I thinking the wrong way?

Comment: You are thinking the wrong way. Nothing with trigonometric identities. Just, given what $x$ and $y$ are, what is $y + \gamma\cos x$?

Comment: I know that $y+\gamma\cos(x)=\alpha v$. So $v = \frac{y+\gamma \cos(x)}{\alpha}$. But substitution gives $v=v$ which doesnt mean anything.

Comment: And $t = x - \frac{y+\gamma\cos x}{\alpha}$. Thus $$g_{\alpha,\gamma}(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}x - \frac{y+\gamma\cos x}{\alpha}\\ \frac{y+\gamma\cos x}{\alpha}\end{pmatrix}.$$ Substitution means just the verification that $g_{\alpha,\gamma} \circ f_{\alpha,\gamma} = \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: Ah I see, I was totally thinking the wrong way. Thank you very much!